# What does it mean "ain't no maybe"?

Tags: idioms, american-english, colloquial-language

I.e. "There ain't no maybe".

The "ain't" can be converted into "is no". So the result is "There is no no maybe". How to understand this?

Comment: It's just an example of "double negative" (typical of relaxed colloquial / uneducated speech). Semantically, it makes more sense to say the ***ain't*** can be converted to ***is*** in the cited context. Even Yoda gets that right, with *There is no try, there is only do*.

Comment: From FumbleFingers' explanation, the sentence can be understood as, "I am absolutely certain," with forceful emphasis on that degree of certainty.

Comment: Yup, "there's no maybe" = definitely

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I think it would be a duplicate if the OP's phrase was "ain't no nobody", with the additional "no" the phrase could be confusing to non-native speakers.

Comment: @Peter: But "ain't no nobody" would be a ***triple** negative* - which unlike the commonplace *double negative,* simply doesn't occur in natural speech.

Comment: Can you tell us about the context where you found this sentence?

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  a poor fellow in the American South might say "I ain't never had no money".

Comment: @TRomano So might a poor fellow in Wisconsin or California; the South is not alone in maintaining ME usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase

> ain't no

is informal slang (AmE Southern) meaning

> isn't

and may be used as an intensifier

> There ain't no maybe
>   *There definitely isn't a maybe*
>   *There is certainly*
>
> There ain't no nothing
>   *There is definitely something*

the usage does not follow the usual double negative meaning but is idiomatic.

Comment: I see no justification for labeling the usage "AmE Southern". To the best of my knowledge, it's common *everywhere*. But if people specifically want to associate it with a geographical region, they're far more likely to cite *Cockney* (UK Southern). It's *old* too - there are plenty of examples in Dickens, and I'm sure it wasn't remotely "new" even when he was writing (faithfully recording how lower-class Londoners spoke).

Comment: Imagine the confusion of a person who learns "ain't" in venues like this one, and then encounters "There ain't no maybe" as actually spoken in, say, rural Georgia: "Dayaynomaybeh."

Answer (score 1):

**There ain't no maybe** usually means that the speaker feels the situation to be clear and absolute, contrary to what another person may have said.

> Maybe a stranger came and ate that pie, Ma.
>   -- There ain't no maybe. You done ate it.

The locution is second-cousin to **don't give me that!**